# Can i have more than one desktop installed and then choose which one to use?

Tags: multiple-desktops

My friend just told me, That i could have more than one desktops in Ubuntu and then choose which one to use when the Ubuntu starts up and goes to login screen. I have Ubuntu 12.10 and i think my default desktop is unity, so can i have gnome desktop and more desktops? And if so, How and where to install them and how to use them?

Comment: no, i asked also, where to get it? and how to install it? and how to use it?

Comment: That question covers: How to get it, and how to install it. How to use it is much to big of a topic to be covered here.  Have a look at each DE's doc pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes thats what said in that link .

so as you asked , if you want to install gnome-shell

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

I like KDE , to get it you can do

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

IF you want some light desktops

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: and can you recommend me some other good desktops? and how to install them by terminal? thank you.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: thanks, i have another question also, if i install gnome desktop and KDE and have unity as well, is it possible that my PC or ubuntu might get slower? or is it possible to have high amount of CPU usage?

Comment: yes surely that will happen because background their deamons will run parallel ,so more cpu usage .

Comment: Add your subsequent questions to your original question so that your original question is **complete** for whoever reads it and then you can delete the comments.